# Filtering a query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using QUERY in google sheets to import data from one tab to another in the sam sheet. However, I would like to filter the data please by a specific team - basically only selecting the cells in column F which have a value of "Team B" in their column B

Any idea how I would do this please?

Comment: Welcome back to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `where` clause, like this:

`=query(Sheet2!A1:Z, "select F where B = 'Team B' ", 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You may find `FILTER` an easier option.

Suppose your source data sheet is named `Sheet2`. Try:

`=FILTER(Sheet2!F2:F, Sheet2!B2:B="Team B")`